# Inject URL() Spring Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wish to inject the Java `URL` class into my Spring project, however URL takes an argument (of the URL you wish to open).

How can I go about doing this?

I currently have

```
private HttpURLConnection getConnectionHandler(String urlToPing) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ProtocolException {
        URL url = new URL(urlToPing);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        return connection;
    }
```

Comment: Why not inject property value instead?

Comment: I have no control over this class, its the built in URL std Java class @Leon

Comment: Just change `String urlToPing` to `URL urlToPing`...

Comment: Where are you getting the value from?

Answer (score 1):

Spring already converts a `String` into an `URL` it does this out-of-the-box.

Simple change the method signature to use an `URL` instead of a `String`.

Comment: I'm talking about injecting the whole URL class into my class so I no longer need to call new URL

Comment: As mentioned spring already does that... Just change the type from String to URL... Spring will inject a URL instead of a String. You don't need to do anything for it.